# Which folder of a web application war should jasperreports.properties be located?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a web application that uses Jasper Reports. I want to tweak some properties without editing the source (I've lost it). In the compiled web application in which folder should jasperreports.properties be located in order to get loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jasper.properties is looked up by jasper reports in the classpath, so it can be directly in the WEB-INF/classes folder, or in the root folder of any of the jars in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 3):

If you put it in WEB-INF/classes it can be loaded from the CLASSPATH.