# jasperreports images are always blurry

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports

A simple report with only a png in it.

Png's dpi is 96, which looks pretty sharp. However, every time i export the report, be it to .docx or to pdf, only an awfully blurry image appears.

i've tried setting

```
net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi
```

to 300, and to 96

both in ireports and directly on the report's jrxml as a property.

Nothing works.

exception

I've lost many days googling this matter but still no answers.

**Update 1**

I've been able to trace the cause of this strange behavior to itext. It seems that it has to do something with it.

**Update 2**

Here's the jrxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="carta_policia" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fbda9a68-7549-438c-a8ad-b3aedaf0b2d4">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.background.image" value="C:\Users\thou\workspace\cujillo\WebContent\resources\reports\fondo.png"/>
    <property name="ireport.background.image.properties" value="false,true,0.25,0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi" value="96"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:/Users/thou/workspace/cujillo/WebContent/resources/reports/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="R_RADICADO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DATA_SOURCE" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="R_ASUNTO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="R_LOCALIDAD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="R_IMAGE_RENDERER" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="R_PRINT_BACKGROUND" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band height="752"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="371" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealSize">
                <reportElement uuid="dbadb500-4011-415b-bd98-4236532783c4" x="234" y="147" width="75" height="63"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\thou\\workspace\\cujillo\\WebContent\\resources\\reports\\alcaldia mayor.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image scaleImage="Clip">
                <reportElement uuid="ecf7dbe3-4369-41a8-ba49-db98ba5ef478" x="309" y="151" width="75" height="63"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\thou\\workspace\\cujillo\\WebContent\\resources\\reports\\alcaldia mayor.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="104" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="11" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="209" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: jasperreports version? what pdf reader software are you using? have you tried with a different one? I'm also using jasperreports with PNG images without problems.

Comment: @TheBronx ireport  5.04, jasperreports 5.00.

Comment: I haven't noticed this with my reports.  Can you show the XML from the jasper report where you include the image?

Comment: when the images are blurry in .pdf and in .docx, it's probably not an itext specific problem.

Comment: @DMoses updated the question body with the jrxml's code

Comment: Can you export to docx, right click on image and go to size.  What are the scale height/width percentages?

Comment: @DMoses both are 133%. However, when i change them to 100%, the image gets smaller but equally blurry.

Comment: It is working for me when it's 100%, It obviously looks blurry if I have the word document zoomed in so the image is bigger than it really is, but otherwise 100% should work.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you put the images you use somewhere network accessible?  I changed your report to point at my own images and I didn't have any problem with image quality in pdf or docx.  Could you take a screeshot of the pdf export vs the docx export?

Answer (score 2):

Although we've raised the DPI setting in our presentations, I've implemented a [custom exporter](https://code.google.com/p/pptx-shape-exporter/), which exports charts as powerpoint shapes and not as raster images.
At least for .docx it's feasible to implement something similar.

Before I've started the shape export classes, I've tried to use EMF ([1](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/518695/excel-image-quality-awful#node-576441),[2](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/bug_files/jexcelapiexporter.java)) as an image format, but this is quite limited, e.g. it doesn't embed fonts.

I haven't searched further in the direction, but maybe you can [transform an intermediate SVG image](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/511011/vectorial-images-pdf-report-wo-raster) to something (raster/vector) which can be embedded into .docx/.pdf.

Have you checked the images inside .docx-Zip-file? ... are the plain images also blurry or just when they are displayed by Word/LibreOffice. And of course the images should change after you changed the DPI setting - if not, try to put a [jasperreports.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914220/which-folder-of-a-web-application-war-should-jasperreports-properties-be-located) in the classpath

Comment: Tried both suggestions. The duke image that comes with the samples also loses resolution and placing the jasperreports.properties changed nothing. thanks though

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error, but no luck. Jasper embedded the huge png as-is in the docx. For the PDF part, I've only used ireports PDF previewer, but it also looked good. Originally I've thought you are  talking about generated charts and not images - at least for static images, I haven't found a re-sampling with docx exporter or the other used jrimage* classes